# Record video with pause

Tags: android, mediarecorder

How I can pause video when recording?
I read that Android does not support this function, but the default video camera on the Samsung Galaxy S3 does it perfectly.
How does Samsung do it?

Comment: I've never used video recording but maybe they just create another file after resuming and when recording completes they stick them together?

Comment: Samsung, as a manufacturer and publisher of an Android release, is fairly free to add additional non-standard functionality, which may or may not be available to others developing for their devices and probably would not be available to others developing for other devices.